# Яка вимова приголосних перед [й]?

Tags: фонетика

Менї насамперед цїкавить:

- «мяка» підґрупа, тобто **д**, **т**, **з**, **с**, (**дз**, ) **ц**, **л**, **н**, котру можна скоротити [через відповідні префікси] до **д** і **з**, бо гинші випадки можливі, але рідкіші; за основу беру коротке слово *зʼява*; однак якщо є можливість — можна покрити всї приголосні;
- стандард і узус стосовно вище.

Які варіяції бачу:

1. Жодних впливів, тобто [зй]. Найпоширенїший запис, нп. в [Горосї](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F/%D0%B7%27%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%B0) чи [Погрібного](http://irbis-nbuv.gov.ua/ulib/item/UKR0001490).
2. [Надкоротка павза](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensions_to_the_International_Phonetic_Alphabet#Prosodic_notation_and_indeterminate_sounds), тобто [з.й], як ві вимові декотрих в словах як *зʼорати*, *зʼекономити* ітд; на жаль, більшість джерел не включають в транскріпціях таке явище; однак особисто таку вимову не чую, тому здається, що малоімовірно.
3. Як [і], тобто [з'й], що схоже на **з** в *зірка*, але з [й];
4. Як [ь], тобто [з"й] як в [*паризьєн*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%8C%D1%94%D0%BD), тобто *зьява*, де **з** повністю мяка, і *зʼява* тотожні.

Здогадки, чому два останнї випадки можливі, або причини, чому маю сумнїви в перший пункт:

- Звук [й] — [палатальний](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82) приголосний — в МФА [j] — і часто позначений як *мякий* приголосний. Тобто чому правило [уподібнення за мякістю](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D1%96_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B2_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96#%D0%90%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D0%BC%27%D1%8F%D0%BA%D1%96%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8E) уникає цього звука?
- Має велику гісторію ві зміні приголосних, втч. [суттєвих](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%99%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%27%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96) і не лише в словянських мовах.
- Існує термін як *роздїльний мякий знак* і він є по сутї основним, щонайменше для [прізвищ](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil4.htm#par104p12) і [чужомовних слів](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#par93), коли [апостроф](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil1.htm#par6) в таких випадках стосується лише префіксів і складених слів [також «твердих» і «півмяких» приголосних]. Тобто з поміж варіятивних [*Касьян*](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD), *Касіян* чи *Касʼян* — перше буде за правилами.
- Приклади гинших близьких мов. Десь таку фонолоґію має [польська](//pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/Aneks:J%C4%99zyk_polski_-_wymowa_-_zasady#Zmi%C4%99kczenie), де запис [*zjawa*](//pl.wiktionary.org/wiki/zjawa) стає за вимовою як [з'йава]. Білоруська має запис [*зьява*](//verbum.by/?q=%D0%B7%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%B0).
- Запис слів відповідним чином: [*підьїзд*](//google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&q=%22%D0%BF%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%8C%D1%97%D0%B7%D0%B4%22), [*зьїзд*](//google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&q=%22%D0%B7%D1%8C%D1%97%D0%B7%D0%B4%22) ітп ітд. Звісно, це можна також пояснити різними техничними ускладненнями щодо самого апострофа. Хоча таке можна зустрїти і в старих текстах до або під час вводу апострофа: [*зьїсти*](//zbruc.eu/node/53900) (1891).
- Явище як [епентеза](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B0), тобто вставка сонорних як [л] і [н] перед губними: говіркові *мнясо*, *здоровля* ітд, і літературні *роблю*, *земля* ітд.

Тож чи справдї тут [зй] чи не все так просто? Про всяк зазначу, що зміни звуків, як в *Наталія* > *Наталья* > *Наталя* чи в подвоєння приголосних не дуже цїкаві.

Comment: Натрапив на [роботу](http://dnpb.gov.ua/wp-content/uploads/2022/07/71604-2.pdf#page=16) пана [Науменка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Науменко_Володимир_Павлович) — пише, що [мягшить](https://twiukraine.com/system/media_attachments/files/109/711/908/563/645/270/original/ddc518898e25d456.png), але [частково](https://twiukraine.com/system/media_attachments/files/109/711/944/951/740/763/original/bca7b04233576fa1.png). Тобто третій варіянт. Хотїло ся би сучасні джерела.